# Extending Ext.data.reader.Json

Tags: extjs, extjs4

What method do I have to override so as to extend Ext.data.reader.Json (for a TreeStore)?
My new Reader must just take json object already parsed by base Reader class and rearrange several items in it. I just need to understand which Reader method is invoked by Proxy when Proxy wants to get parsed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getResponseData is where it gets the data from the response and puts it into an appropriate format for the reader. Here you could make transformations to the JSON and then just let the reader do it's thing.

readRecords is where it turns the JSON into models, so you could also modify that.

The absolute latest is in onProxyLoad in Ext.data.Store, where it gets the returned records from the response & calls the loadRecords method to populate the store.

If it were me I would make an effort to do the first method, since it's the easiest thing to override.

Comment: getResponseData only? But there's also readRecords. I don't know which to choose. And getResponseData doesn't even return ready Models and I neeed method to process final json hierarchy.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you override getResponseData you can change the JSON in such a way that it can be read by the tree.

Comment: From what documentation says, getResponse data only extracts useful segment of raw data and doesn't return final Models.

Comment: That's correct, that's what I said above. I suggest you update your question to be less vague, preferably with an example.

Comment: Well, I only need to know which method is called by Proxy (or Store?) when Proxy (or store) wants to get ready models from Reader so as to put them into a store! I only need to implement my own logic at the latest stage of data processing - kind of postprocessing (but before it gets put into Store).